# Mandatory to NOT something

Tags: adverbs, antonyms, subject-verb-inversion

I'm looking for some type of inverse of "mandatory to *not*", as in "mandatory to not have any errors in your exam" or "mandatory to not read foreign words in the book." (Those must sound awful to a native speaker, but I hope the meaning is clear enough.)

"Forbidden" or "disallowed" are too strong in this sense, but "optional" is also at the wrong end of the spectrum. Is there a better fit, or should I use a longer explanation?

Comment: I don't understand, do you want the inverse of "mandatory to not" or a synonym of _forbidden_?

Comment: Mandatory means something that _has to be done_, so 'mandatory to not' is synonymous with _forbidden_. What are you actually trying to convey?

Comment: The meaning is clearer with the phrasing *mandatory to not* -- the use of an antonym is affect readability/ understandability.

Comment: Folks! *mandatory to not* is not the same as *forbidden* -- think again.

Comment: @Kris: how does *"mandatory to not"* differ from *"forbidden"*? Maybe you or the OP could help us with this. They both describe things you are not strongly encouraged not to do.

Comment: If I understand the question, you could use "allowable", something like "It is allowable to make errors in your exam". But the question isn't very clear. Why do you introduce the words "forbidden" and "disallowed" in the second paragraph? (they say *the same* as "mandatory to not").

Comment: What *do* you mean by "inverse", and what *are* you looking for an antonym for? The current wording is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**mustn't** as in must not

if

> "Forbidden" or "disallowed" are too strong in this sense

mustn't must surely be okay...

"mandatory to not have any errors in your exam" --> "your exam mustn't contain any errors"

"mandatory to not read foreign words in the book." --> "you mustn't read foreign words in the book."

Answer (score 2):

[Forbidden](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forbidden?s=t) or [prohibited](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prohibited) could both be an appropriate counter to 'mandatory'. For a milder sense, you could use '[discouraged](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discourage)' in the sense that you'd be 'making clear disapproval of' something, without any significant enforcement.

Comment: "Strongly discouraged" is good to.

Answer (score 0):

mandatory - you need to

optional - you can, but you don't have to

---

not mandatory - you don't have to = optional

not optional - you have to = mandatory

---

It is not optional to check for errors.

Having your eyes open while driving a car is not optional.